# Create Facebook Graph API user access token without UI

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I'm trying to grab the number of likes on my Instagram posts with [this api](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-api/reference/ig-media/).

I can successfully call the endpoints using the access token generated from the [Graph API Explorer](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/), but I'm trying to find a way to generate the access token programmatically. The [API docs](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/guides/access-tokens) have examples on how to request an access token from a Web/Mobile UI, but I'm wanting this script to sit on a server and run as a cronjob, etc.

I've seen some resources on how to convert the short-lived token into a long-lived token from code, but is it possible to generate the initial token from code?

Comment: _"but is it possible to generate the initial token from code?"_ - no, it is not.

Answer (score 0):

This approach might not work for everyone, but I ended up using a webdriver to automate the OAuth login process.

```py
import requests
from selenium import webdriver

app_id = 1234567890
secret = '...'
redirect = 'https://whatever' # needs to be added in app settings

fb_username = '...'
fb_password = '...'

login_url = 'https://www.facebook.com/v14.0/dialog/oauth'
login_url += f'?client_id={app_id}&redirect_uri={redirect}'

b = webdriver.Firefox()
b.get(login_url)

b.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="email"]').send_keys(fb_username)
b.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="pass"]').send_key(fb_password)
b.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="loginbutton"]').click()

code = b.current_url.split('=')[1]

url = 'https://graph.facebook.com/v14.0/oauth/access_token?'
url += f'client_id={app_id}'
url += f'&redirect_uri={redirect}'
url += f'&client_secret={secret}'
url += f'&code={code}'

resp = requests.get(url)

if resp.status_code == 200:
    print(resp.json()['access_token'])
```

Comment: Is the redirect value important, bro? What else if I do not have the redirect?

Comment: @HanVanPham yes the api requires the redirect_url parameter. You also have to add the url to the list of approved redirect urls in your facebook app via the dashboard